# Javascript div box that follow cursor position

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a circle navigation button to follow mouse movement when the cursor is inside a certain box.

```js
var cer = document.getElementById('cerchio');
var pro = document.getElementById('prova');


pro.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
var e = window.event;
var x = e.clientX;
var y = e.clientY;
cer.style.top = y + "px";
cer.style.left = x + "px";
cer.style.transition = "2s";
});

pro.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
cer.style.top = "15px";
cer.style.left = "15px";
});
```

```css
#prova {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#cerchio {
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
border: 1px solid red;
border-radius: 90px;
position: absolute;
left: 15px;
top: 15px;
}

#innercircle {
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
position: relative;
left: 40px;
top: 30px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="prova">
<div id="innercircle">
<div id="cerchio"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

so it actually follows the first position of the mouse inside the black bordered box, i want it to update the cursor positioning every time and follow it, also i don't want the red circle to go out the red box, any suggestion? please javascript only not jquery, thanks!

Comment: [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) is non-standard. Use `e` as an argument instead. Use `mousemove` if you want the circle to move every time.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is your usage of `window.event` and wrong event handlers.
Here's a solution that uses standard event handling:

```js
var cer = document.getElementById('cerchio');
var pro = document.getElementById('prova');
var proR = pro.getBoundingClientRect();
var cirR = cer.getBoundingClientRect();
// radii
var rW = (cirR.right - cirR.left) / 2;
var rH = (cirR.bottom - cirR.top) / 2;
// page coords of center
var oX = (proR.right + proR.left) / 2;
var oY = (proR.bottom + proR.top) / 2;
var x, y;
// max movement
var max = 15;

function setPos(x, y) {
  cer.style.left = (x + oX - rW) + "px";
  cer.style.top = (y + oY - rH) + "px";
}

pro.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  setPos(0, 0);
});

pro.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  // 0,0 is at center
  x = e.clientX - oX;
  y = e.clientY - oY;
  // limit to max
  if (x < -max) x = -max;
  if (x > max) x = max;
  if (y < -max) y = -max;
  if (y > max) y = max;
  // set circle position
  setPos(x, y);
});

setPos(0, 0);
```

```css
#prova {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 40px;
}

#innercircle {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#cerchio {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .5s;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#prova,
#innercircle,
#cerchio {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="prova">
  <div id="innercircle">
    <div id="cerchio"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also changed the calculation to

1. determine the x,y values such that the center of the area is (0, 0)
2. limit the values to a set boundary
3. add back the offset to position the circle

Answer (score 0):

"mousemove" is the event you want to track for this as you want the position of the mouse as it moves inside the element. You should also pass the event as a callback to the event handler

I also fixed the positioning using the getBoundingClientRect() method.

```js
var cer = document.getElementById('cerchio');
var pro = document.getElementById('prova');
var innerC = document.getElementById('innercircle');


innerC.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  var square = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  var squareX = square.x;
  var squareY = square.y;
  var squareWidth = square.width;
  var squareHeight = square.height;
  var mouseX = e.clientX;
  var mouseY= e.clientY;

  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;

  cer.style.top = (-squareY + mouseY - (squareHeight / 2 - 15)) + "px";
  cer.style.left = (-squareX + mouseX - (squareWidth / 2 - 15)) + "px";
  cer.style.transition = "2s";
});


innerC.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  cer.style.top = "15px";
  cer.style.left = "15px";
});
```

```css
#prova {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#cerchio {
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
border: 1px solid red;
border-radius: 90px;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
left: 15px;
top: 15px;
}

#innercircle {
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
left: 40px;
top: 30px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="prova">
<div id="innercircle">
<div id="cerchio"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you're using 'mouseover'. This event only activates when the mouse enters the element. This way, if works the first time you move over the rectangle, or when you move between the black and red rectangles.

If you use 'mousemove', it works right.

```js
var cer = document.getElementById('cerchio');
var pro = document.getElementById('prova');


pro.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
var e = window.event;
var x = e.clientX;
var y = e.clientY;
cer.style.top = y + "px";
cer.style.left = x + "px";
cer.style.transition = "2s";
});

pro.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
cer.style.top = "15px";
cer.style.left = "15px";
});
```

```css
#prova {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#cerchio {
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
border: 1px solid red;
border-radius: 90px;
position: absolute;
left: 15px;
top: 15px;
}

#innercircle {
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
position: relative;
left: 40px;
top: 30px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="prova">
<div id="innercircle">
<div id="cerchio"></div>
</div>
</div>
```